# basic JS question: replacing text alert to image alert

Tags: javascript, return-value

I'd really use your help!

Js is not really my thing.. I'm making validation form script in my page and browsing through examples scripts iI run into this:

['required', 'This is a required field.', function(v) {
    return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
   }],

I need to put image instead of 'This is a required field.' Is it the right place? And if.. how should I do it?;(

Thx in advance for any suggestions!:)

Comment: Your Javascript looks pretty strange. Would it be possible for you to post some code into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/TBtaN/ :)
It's a script from this tutorial: http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what are you using, but try this:

```
['required', '<img alt="This is a required field." src="path/to/required.png" />', function(v) { return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v); }],
```

since it's filling the text, it should put the html markup in instead of it, unless it's escaping html.